# intersect function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i did this function for intersect in haskell and it just doesnt work. i know that the aux works but the main one no. Help pleas

```
myintersect ::  Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myintersect a [] = a
myintersect l (h1:t1) = (myintersect (intersectaux h1 l) t1)

intersectaux :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
intersectaux _ [] = []
intersectaux a (h:t) = if a==h then h:intersectaux a t else intersectaux a t
```

Comment: Why do you think the `myintersect` works?

Comment: Furthermore please explain the *reasoning* behind your functions.

Comment: I'm no Haskell expert (just learning it myself), but assuming (from the name) this is supposed to implement some sort of intersection of 2 lists, your base case is wrong in `myintersect` - the intersection of an empty list with any other should be the empty list.

Comment: myintersect doesnt work. what i said is that myintersectaux works because i tested but the main one, myintersect doesnt work. unless the second inserted list is just an element it will always return []. but thanks for the answer

Comment: you re right Robin. still doesnt work tho...

Comment: myintersect ::  Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    myintersect [] _ = []
    myintersect l (h1:t1) = (myintersect (intersectaux h1 l) t1)

    intersectaux :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
    intersectaux _ [] = [] 
    intersectaux a (h:t) = if a==h then h:intersectaux a t else intersectaux a t

Comment: @PedroNovais: can you specify how you "constructed" these functions? What reasoning did you apply to write these?

Comment: the auxiliar is a function that when you give an element and a list it will return the elements from the list that are equal to the first element. thse main one is a fucntion that when you give two lists ,one with just aleatory elements and the other with the elements that you want to intersect. the result is the same as the auxiliar but intersecting a list with another list of elements instead intersecting a list with one element @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When other members ask for additional information, it is usually best to [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problems with the current approach:

in your approach, the `intersectaux` aims to *filter* the list, such that only the elements that are equal to `a` remain. So that means that for `intersectaux 4 [1,4,2,5]`, it will return `[4]`. So it means that after this "round", the list will only contain elements that are all the same: elements equal to `a`.

In a next "round" we filter with a (potentially) different element. If we filter with an element equal to the previous `a`, then the result will be equal to the given list: a list that still contains only elements equal to `a`. If the element is however different, then it will remove all the elements from the list, since `a2 /= a1` (`a1` being the "old" `a`, and `a2` the "new" `a`) so the result will be empty.

After all "rounds" are finished, we return the result that will, based on the above, contain only elements that are equal, or an empty list.

## A solution using `elem`

The intersection of two lists can be defined as:

> A list that contains all the elements that occur in the *first* list, and the *second* list.

In Haskell lists can have an infinite length, making it hard to solve the problem. But in this answer, I will ignore that: we make the *assumption* that the second list has a finite length. More advanced strategies (like for example each time taking a limited number of elements in the two lists, and calculating the intersection of these finite collections).

In order to calculate the intersection, we can enumerate over the first list, and for every element in that list, check if that element occurs in the second list as well. We can check if a list `l` contains an element `x` with [**`elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem): by checking `elem x l`.

For the intersection, we then have three cases:

1. the first list is exhausted (empty), in which case the result is an empty list;
2. the first list is not empty, and the first element of that list is an element of the second list, in that case we *yield* that element, and recurse on the tail of the list; and
3. the first list is not empty, the first element does *not* occur in the second list, we then recurse on the tail of the list.

For example:

```
intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect [] _ = []
intersect (x:xs) l | elem x l = x : intersect xs l
                   | otherwise = intersect xs l
```

The above will yield elements multiple times if they occur *multiple* times in the first list (if these occur multiple times in the second list, then this will *not* act as a "multiplier").

The above is not very efficient if the elements can be `Ord`ered, or if these are `Hashable`. So the above can still be improved (significantly).

Comment: i understood all that you said and i know how to make this function the way you did. i just want to know why my way doesnt work... but thank you